# How to make mobile applications install and run in CHINA?Any option for the app to work without using VPN?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit, great-firewall-of-china

Recently, I gave an iOS build to my client to test an app. I did it by using Unity and ARKit. From the client's feedback, he downloaded the application but the app is not initializing. In order to let the app to initialize, it requires Internet connection. I used a Plugin in my app when I contacted them, they told me that they are using **Google's Firebase** in their backend. Is this the reason that the app has been blocked or any other issues? Any suggestion?.

Btw, **my client cannot use VPN**. Is there a way to run something in code to change to VPN?

Comment: Are you able to solve this problem?

Comment: No..I think ...It wont work...if you are using Anything related to google in your app...

Comment: I am using firebase in my app. But I want to know that, If we choose using VPN for chinese market then we have to do something in our code to support VPN? or VPN is device dependent, we don't need to do any code changes?
Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Since you are using Firebase it wont work in China.The user who is installing would require a VPN to install the app.Thats how our client installed the app there.But people there do not want to use VPN knowingly.Either you need to find a substitute for firebase.I do not know anything about VPN and how to integrate in our code.Paid VPN may(not sure) allow this thing but once the govt finds out the VPN they will block it.So I dont that is a good idea to use VPN.The alternative for Firebase in china is BAIDU I think.May be someone here in stack can give us more clarity into this

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help.